# Google Sheet Query Count Pivot

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

Need on creating a query formula in google sheets where the store number will fall in a row and the Month Added in a column and have a count of the month added per store number.

Im trying to do the query pivot formula instead since the pivot table i created is giving me this error already: This pivot table is trying to produce too many cells. Make it smaller by adjusting row and column breakouts or filtering the source data.

Here's the sample data link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UkY-RxjI_BfD6POmv7PkWx8Uuf-erxFrBrguP8XLrG4/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=transpose(query(hstack(B2:B,arrayformula(if(len(C2:C),eomonth(C2:C,),))),"select Col2, count(Col2) Where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1 format Col2 'm-yy'",0))
```

[image]

Comment: It did not work on the bigger data.

Comment: Cool... Hopefully someone else will pitch in with a working formula!

Comment: anyone who has other ideas?

Comment: Just want to reopen this. If another column needs to add as the condition like the only Status shown should be Complete.How can we update the formula?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=transpose(
  query(
    query({Sheet1!B1:C},
    "select count(Col1),Col1,Col2 where Col1 is not null group by Col1,Col2",1),
  "select Col3,max(Col1) group by Col3 pivot Col2",1)
 )
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you want but the result appears to match your example.

N.B. - the TRANSPOSE is required as the *pivot* in the outer QUERY needs to be done the 'wrong way round' otherwise the format of the 'Month added' cells seems to get messed up. (At least that's what's happening when I try it...)